# Access an attribute from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a part of my model (Partner)

```html
before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.name = name.upcase
    self.institution = institution.upcase
    self.position = position.upcase
    self.street = street.upcase
    self.neighborhood = neighborhood.upcase
    self.city = city.upcase
    self.state = state.upcase
    self.email = email.upcase
    self.birth_city = birth_city.upcase
    self.spouse = spouse.upcase
  end
```

street and neighborhood are attributes from address model. By this way, i´m getting an error before saving it to db. How can I solve it?

Comment: Is your `Partner` model associated with the `Address` model (with a `has_many` or a `belongs_to` association)? How that that association look like? Do you want to `upcase` the attributes on the `Address` or in the `Partner` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be better doing is delegating those attributes to the `Address` model, and using `autosave` to have them persist when you save the  `Partner` model..

```
class Partner
  has_one :address, autosave: true

  delegate :street, :neighborhood, to: :address

  # callback code here
end
```

If you want to upcase all attributes, you can use a combination of `assign_attributes` and [`transform_values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/transform_values.rb):

```
before_validation(on: :create) do
  assign_attributes(attributes.transform_values(&:upcase))
end
```

Comment: thank you so much! seeing it, I realized that I use a bad solution to fix my problem.